# Conversation touchs other sessions in grammy

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, grammy

I am developing telegram bot using [grammy](https://grammy.dev/). I use two sessions in my bot: one with external storage, one with memory storage (for conversations).

```js
bot.use(session({
    profile : {
        storage : require('./storage.js')
    },
    conversation : {}, type : 'multi'
}));
```

I am traking when different methods of storage was called and was suprised when I found that each time when user enters the conversation profile storage's write method is called with no changes. I didn't expect such behaviour and still don't understand it. Encoding to [documentation](https://grammy.dev/plugins/conversations#installation-with-multi-sessions) conversation should only use session provided for them (conversation session).

Comment: I also dont get why changing conversation.session props reflects the changes for all user sessions

Answer (score 1):

> each time when user enters the conversation profile storage's write method

I assume you use `await conversation.wait()` for this purpose. This method [creates a new context object](https://grammy.dev/plugins/conversations#waiting-for-updates) and you have to work with it instead of the original context object.

This means that instead of writing

```
const {message} = await conversation.wait();
```

you'll have to use

```
const newCtx = await conversation.wait();
const {message} = newCtx;
```

Working with the new context object fixed my problem with values dissapearing from the context object used later on.

```
await ctx.reply("Напишите название книги");

ctx.session.myValue = 1; // will be added

const newCtx = await conversation.wait();

ctx.session.someValue = 1; // will not be added
newCtx.session.anotherValue = 1; // will be added
```

Not the prettiest solution, but it works!

Comment: It works man! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With [grammyjs](https://grammy.dev/) conversation plugin, you should use **conversation.session** utility to deal with sessions objects as indicated in the documentation [#rule-iii-use-convenience-functions](https://grammy.dev/plugins/conversations#rule-iii-use-convenience-functions) :

```
// `ctx.session` only persists changes for the most recent context object
conversation.session.myProp = 42; // more reliable!
```